# Redshift limitation on LIKE operator in CASE statement

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am running into an issue where if I have more than 15 `LIKE` operators within a case statement, I get an error `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Here is an example of what I am doing against a table with 60 million rows:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN field LIKE '%value%' THEN 'result'
       WHEN field LIKE '%value2%' THEN 'result2'
       .... 14 more of those
  END
```

I haven't seen this limitation documented anywhere. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: this error doesn't happen when i test - tried 15 and tried 25. please try to generate some test data that you can share which demonstrates this issue.

Comment: I can't replicate it with test data because I think it is based on how much data is scanned in the query. The table I have is 60 million rows. If I run the query on a subset of the table, then it works.

Comment: can you try dissecting the data to see whether there is a particular row causing the issue? with limit and offset?

Comment: How are you executing the query, is it from code? i.e. where is that java error coming from, as it doesn't look like a Redshift error to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a driver issue. I was initially using 1.2.16.1027 and upgraded to 1.2.20.1043 and I am no longer receiving the error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's an out-of-memory error.

I think you have some options:

- use an intermediate table before doing the `like` processing (or use intermediate tables to process subsets of your initial data)
- bump up the number of queue slots that you're using for this query to have more memory available https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_wlm_query_slot_count.html
- take a look at the `explain` output to see if it gives you clues about what's going wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could [Create a Scalar Python User-Defined Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html) to replace the `LIKE` comparisons.

Then, just use:

```
SELECT f_myfunc(field)
```